# qlik-auth how to get dynamic user object into the request var

Tags: node.js, authentication, qliksense

I am using the qlik-auth library for node js which is now authenticating ok but only with the statically predefined user object.

This url is running on port **8000** and this url is directly accessed by the **qlik virtual proxy**.

How exactly do I get a user object in the node request var?

```
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    var profile = {
        "UserDirectory": "dir",
        "UserId": "usd",
        "Attributes":[
            {"type": "a type", "value": "a value"},
        ]
    };

    var options = {
        Certificate: './client.pfx',
        PassPhrase: 'dev',
        BackUrl: 'http://ip/login.php',
    };

    qlikauth.requestTicket(req, res, profile, options);

}).listen(port, '0.0.0.0');
```